# stop scrolling of an element in a scrollview In android

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a Scrollview that contains some textview and a listview. one of those textsviews is the title of listview. when scrolling, I need that this textview remain on the top of screen. how can I do that?

Comment: Use `ListView.addHeaderView(your title textView);`

Comment: Can you post some image that what you actually want.?

Comment: just like Instagram list. each list item has a title and an image. when you scroll the list, the title stop in the top but the image continue scrolling.